# How to use jQuery mouseover from an array?

Tags: jquery

I have a sample code:

```
<a href=""></a>
<textarea></textarea>
<object></object>
<img src="" />
<div id="content"></div>
```

I had using this:

```
jQuery("a").mouseover(function() {
    alert();
 });
 jQuery("textarea").mouseover(function() {
    alert();
 });
 jQuery("object").mouseover(function() {
    alert();
 }); 
 jQuery("img").mouseover(function() {
    alert();
 });
 jQuery("#content").mouseover(function() {
    alert();
 });
```

Can I using this ?

```
var object = ["a","textarea","object","img", "content"]; 
jQuery.each(object, function() {
   jQuery(this).mouseover(function(){
      alert();
   });  
});
```

How to ideas using jQuery mouseover from an array ?

Comment: What exactly do you want to be doing with this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the context of your `.each()` loop, `this` will be the current element from the array, i.e., a string, except that each string will be wrapped in an object (as explained at the [`$.each()` doco page](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)), so you need to use `this.toString()`:

```
jQuery(this.toString()).mouseover(function(){
```

...and then it will have the same effect as `jQuery("a")`, `jQuery("textarea")` and so forth. Which will work as long as each string is a valid selector. Or, better, make use of the arguments that jQuery passes to your function:

```
jQuery.each(object, function(i, val) {
   jQuery(val).mouseover(function(){
```

The final element in your array is an `id`, so it needs a `#`:

```
var object = ["a","textarea","object","img", "#content"];
// add # here --------------------------------^
```

Then in the context of the mouseover handler, `this` is the element that the event occurred on, so just use `jQuery(this)` rather than `jQuery("#" + this)`. Putting that all together:

```
jQuery.each(object, function(i, val) {
   jQuery(val).mouseover(function(){
       jQuery(this).css(...);           
   });  
});​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GBtFY/

Answer (score 1):

When you access `this` you don't prepend `#`.

As for the array, I would just use a CSS selector:

```
$('a, textarea, object, img, #content').mouseover(function(){
  $(this).css(...);
});
```

Comment: If you are going to downvote, please comment saying why. I'm happy to edit my answer if it has an issue.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would give a common attribute to those elements which needs the mouse over function. like a classname or a data-value attribute.
For example:

```
<a href="" data-hover="true"></a>
<textarea data-hover="true" ></textarea>
<object data-hover="true" ></object>
<img data-hover="true" src="" />
<div data-hover="true" id="content"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-hover]').bind('mouseover', function(){
        alert('Completed');
    });
});
</script>
```